# Regex pattern counting with repetitive words

Tags: python, regex

I try to write a python function that counts a specific word in a string.

My regex pattern doesn't work when the word I want to count is repeated multiple times in a row. The pattern seems to work well otherwise.

Here is my function

```
import re

def word_count(word, text):
    return len(re.findall('(^|\s|\b)'+re.escape(word)+'(\,|\s|\b|\.|$)', text, re.IGNORECASE))
```

When I test it with a random string

```
>>> word_count('Linux', "Linux, Word, Linux")
2
```

When the word I want to count is adjacent to itself

```
>>> word_count('Linux', "Linux Linux")
1
```

Comment: Note that `'\b'` is a backspace character, `'\x08'`, not `'\\b'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in your regex. Your regex is using 2 capture groups and `re.findall` will return any capture groups if available. That needs to change to non-capture groups using `(?:...)`

Besides there is reason to use `(^|\s|\b)` as `\b` or word boundary is suffice which covers all the cases besides `\b` is zero width.

Same way `(\,|\s|\b|\.|$)` can be changed to `\b`.

So you can just use:

```
def word_count(word, text):
     return len(re.findall(r'\b' + re.escape(word) + r'\b', text, re.I))
```

This will give:

```
>>> word_count('Linux', "Linux, Word, Linux")
2
>>> word_count('Linux', "Linux Linux")
2
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I just edited my question to be more precise. I want to count a word that may be repeated *multiple* times in a row. So word_count('Linux', 'Linux Linux Linux') would return 3.

Comment: I had a typo which is fixed. This will return `3` for `word_count('Linux', 'Linux Linux Linux')`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is 100% because I don't understand the part about passing the function the word to search for when you are just looking for words that repeat in a string.  So maybe consider...

```
import re

pattern = r'\b(\w+)( \1\b)+'

def word_count(text):
    split_words = text.split(' ')
    count = 0
    for split_word in split_words:
        count = count + len(re.findall(pattern, text, re.IGNORECASE))
    return count

word_count('Linux Linux Linux Linux')
```

Output:

```
4
```

Maybe it helps.

UPDATE:  Based on comment below...

```
def word_count(word, text):
    count = text.count(word)
    return count

word_count('Linux', "Linux, Word, Linux")
```

Output:

```
2
```

Comment: OP is looking to "count a specific word in a string". For example `"Linux"` occurs in `"Linux, Word, Linux"` twice, so the function should return 2.

Comment: Updated the answer.  Maybe that's useful?

Comment: That's counting substrings, not words. E.g. `word_count('race', 'racer')` is 1, but should be 0.

Comment: If you really wanted to use a `.count` method, you could split the string into a list, e.g. `re.split(r'\W+', text)`, but it makes it harder to do a case-insensitive search.